# Different monitor setup at multiple workstations

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook

I have my monitors at work set up to the left of my macbook, and at home to the right. Based on the way my monitors are mounted, I can not change their location to be the same in both of my workstations.

My Mac thinks my second monitor is to the left of the Macbook Pro, but at home my monitor is set up to the right of the Mac and the setup is all wrong.

Is there a way to have my Mac detect the workstation and re-arrange the display's position?

I am running Yosemite on the late 2013 Macbook pro.

Comment: Are they identical monitors?

Answer (score 0):

Different "monitor profiles" within the computers configuration is not something that can be automatically detected due to the computer having no way of knowing the physical alignment of the monitor. This setting must be adjusted every time you "install" a new setup.

There are monitor "profile" programs out there, but to the best of my knowledge, they are only for Windows based PC. One such program is [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/). With said program, you can add different profiles and configurations, but you will have to select the configuration when you are in the actual OS and load the program up.

I have done some research to find a monitor profiling program out there for OSX, but have never been luckily enough to fine one. Looks like we will have to manually change our display setting every time.